# Is there any way I can minimize the js code?

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner in javascript. Looks like the code is too messy. The code I wrote is my limit. How do I minimize the code?

I know there is a way to write it concisely without writing the code separately, but it is still difficult. Please help me ..

```
const CloseBtn01 = document.querySelector(".close01");
const CloseBtn02 = document.querySelector(".close02");
const CloseBtn03 = document.querySelector(".close03");


const btn01 = document.querySelector("#gnbBtn01");
const btn02 = document.querySelector("#gnbBtn02");
const btn03 = document.querySelector("#gnbBtn03");
const layout01 = document.querySelector(".layout01")
const layout02 = document.querySelector(".layout02")
const layout03 = document.querySelector(".layout03")

function closeLayout01() {
   CloseBtn01.addEventListener("click", function(){
      layout01.style.display = "none";
      gsap.to(camera.position, {
         x: cameraPosition.x,
         y: cameraPosition.y,
         z: cameraPosition.z,
         duration: 1.2
      })
   })
}
function closeLayout02() {
   CloseBtn02.addEventListener("click", function(){
      layout02.style.display = "none";
      gsap.to(camera.position, {
         x: cameraPosition.x,
         y: cameraPosition.y,
         z: cameraPosition.z,
         duration: 1.2
      })
   })
}
function closeLayout03() {
   CloseBtn03.addEventListener("click", function(){
      layout03.style.display = "none";
      gsap.to(camera.position, {
         x: cameraPosition.x,
         y: cameraPosition.y,
         z: cameraPosition.z,
         duration: 1.2
      })
   })
}

btn01.addEventListener("click", function(){
   gsap.to(camera.position, {
      x: -4,
      y: 1,
      z: 3.4,
      duration: 1.2,
      onComplete: () => {
         layout01.style.display = "block";
         closeLayout01();
      }
   })
})


btn02.addEventListener("click", function(){
   gsap.to(camera.position, {
      x: 4,
      y: 0.5,
      z: 0,
      duration: 1.2,
      onComplete: () => {
         layout02.style.display = "block";
         closeLayout02();
      }
   })
})

btn03.addEventListener("click", function(){
   gsap.to(camera.position, {
      x: 3,
      y: 0.5,
      z: 5,
      duration: 1.2,
      onComplete: () => {
         layout03.style.display = "block";
         closeLayout03();
      }
   })
})
```

hello! I am a beginner in javascript. Looks like the code is too messy. The code I wrote is my limit. How do I minimize the code?

I know there is a way to write it concisely without writing the code separately, but it is still difficult. Please help me ..

Comment: Add your HTML code here

Comment: I would add a single `closeLayout` and pass the element as argument to that to keep it DRY

Comment: <div class="layout01">
                <div id="tab-box">
                    <div id="tabs">
                        <a href="javascript:;"><img src="img3/close.png" alt="닫기" class="close close01"></a>
                    </div>
                    <ul id="tabBtn" class="tab tab01">
                        <li><a href="#con1" class="active">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#con2">2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#con3">3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  Try editing your post to include the html above.  If you do that you can get the syntax highlighter to handle the display which would make it easier to read and understand the problem, and you'll be more likely to get answers to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not a big improvement but can definitely removes duplicacy

Here it goes as :

```js
function closeLayout03() {
   CloseBtn03.addEventListener("click", function(){
      layout03.style.display = "none";
      gsap.to(camera.position, {
         x: cameraPosition.x,
         y: cameraPosition.y,
         z: cameraPosition.z,
         duration: 1.2
      })
   })
}

// to this

function closeLayout(closeBtn,layout) {
   closeBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
      layout.style.display = "none";
      gsap.to(camera.position, {
         x: cameraPosition.x,
         y: cameraPosition.y,
         z: cameraPosition.z,
         duration: 1.2
      })
   })
}

// and invoking this as 

btn01.addEventListener("click", function(){
   gsap.to(camera.position, {
      x: -4,
      y: 1,
      z: 3.4,
      duration: 1.2,
      onComplete: () => {
         layout01.style.display = "block";
         closeLayout(CloseBtn01,layout01); 
         // similarly for other btns it replaces as
         // closeLayout(CloseBtn02,layout02); 
         // closeLayout(CloseBtn03,layout03); 
      }
   })
})
```